# Principal circle bundles that are smooth foliated

Tags: principal-bundles, foliations

Let $\xi=(\pi,E,B)$ be an orientable circle bundle, i.e., a bundle with fiber $\mathbb{S}^1$ and structural group $G=\textit{Diff}^+(\mathbb{S}^1)$.

*Claim 1*: The bundle $\xi$ admits a structure of $S^1$ principal bundle.

Proof: Let $g$ be a Riemannian metric on $E$, and denote by $l_b$ the length of the fiber over $b\in B$. 
If $\pi(u)=b$ and $z=e^{i\theta}$, then $u\cdot z$ is the point we reach when we proceed in the direction of orientation a distance $(l_b/2\pi)$ on $E_b$ (fiber over $b$) from $u$.

We know that a principal bundle is trivial if and only if it admits a cross section. So, $\xi$ is trivial if and only if admits a cross section. 
This lead us to the Euler class of $\xi$. In fact, a cohomological class $e(\xi)\in H_2(M;\mathbb{R})$ can be obtained as obstruction to the existence of a cross section for $\xi$. Moreover, there exists a one-to-one correspondence between the isomoprhism classes of $\mathbb{S}^1$ bundles over $M$ and cohomology classes in $H^2(M;\mathbb{Z})$ given by $[\xi]\rightarrow e(\xi)$, for instance see (*Geometry of differential forms*, Morita).

When the Euler class $e(\xi)$ is a torsion element we can obtain a codimension one smooth foliation transversal to the fibres of $\xi$, and the bundle $\xi$ with this foliation becomes a foliated bundle. Myioshi (*A remark on torsion Euler  classes of circle bundles*)  showed that the image of the holonomy homomorphism (which characterizes this foliated bundle)
$$\varphi:\pi_1(M)\rightarrow \text{Diff}^+(\mathbb{S}^1)$$
can be taken contained in $SO(2)=\mathbb{S}^1$.

Following that in the same total space $E$ and base $B$ we have two $\mathbb{S}^1$-principal bundles with the same projection. The initial bundle $\xi$, and the bundle $E(\varphi)$ induced by the representation $\varphi:\pi_1(M)\rightarrow SO(2)$ (this induced bundle is a principal bundle and admit a flat connection, see Milnor *On the existence of a connection with curvature zero*, Lemma 1).

**Question: Are the bundles $\xi$ and $E(\varphi)$ equivalent as principal bundles?**

Comment: I do not understand the question. What is $E(\phi)$? The homomorphism $\phi$ gives $\xi$ a structure of a flat $SO(2)$ bundle. Being flat is an extra structure. The underlying circle bundle has not changed. Incidentally, your claim 1 follows by saying that $Diff^+(S^1)$ deformation retracts onto $S^1$.

Comment: The bundle $E(\varphi)$ is defined as follows. Consider the left action of $\pi_1(M)$ on $\tilde{M}\times \mathbb{S}^1$ given by $\alpha\cdot(\tilde{x},g) =(\tilde{x}\cdot\alpha^{-1}, \varphi(\alpha)\cdot g)$. Then, the collapsed space $E(\varphi)$ is the total space of a principal $\mathbb{S}^1$ bundle over $M$ induced by $\varphi$. The action of $\mathbb{S}^1$ on $E(\varphi)$  is not necessarly the same as the action on $E$. These bundles are isomorphic when we consider them as $G=\text{Diff}^+(\mathbb{S}^1)$-bundles.

Comment: If bundles are isomorphic as $Diff^+(S^1)$ bundles, then they are isomorphic as $S^1$ bundles because $Diff^+(S^1)$ deformation retracts onto $S^1$. Specifically, the map of classifying spaces $BS^1\to BDiff^+(S^1)$ has contractible fiber $Diff^+(S^1)/S^1$, which induces a bijection $[M,  BS^1]\to [M, BDiff^+(S^1)]$ of the sets of isomorphism classes of $S^1$ and $Diff^+(S^1)$ bundles over $M$. Of course, all this does not take into account the flat structure, but I gather you disregard it.

Comment: I have a dubt.
 
 When a subgroup $H$ of $G$  is a deformation retract of  $G$, then there exists a bijection $[M,BH]\rightarrow [M,BG]$?

Comment: In your case the map $BH\to BG$ is a homotopy equivalence, see e.g.  the answer in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3341232/homotopy-equivalent-structure-groups-have-h-e-classifying-spaces-if-g-simeq-h?rq=1, and hence you get a bijection of the sets of homotopy classes.

Comment: I should have said "$BH\to BG$ is a weak homotopy equivalence", which is what you need to a bijection of the sets of homotopy classes.